# JasperReports: Instantiating JRDesignChartDatasets

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to instantiate a `JRDesignChartDataset` object so that I can pass it in to the constructor of a `JRDesignPieDataset` instance like so:

```
JRDesignPieDataset pieDataset = new JRDesignPieDataset(new JRDesignChartDataset());
```

This produces a compiler error in Eclipse, complaining that it **Cannot instantiate the type JRDesignChartDataset**...?!?!

I've made sure that I've imported it from the correct package:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignChartDataset;
```

And I've checked the current (4.1.3) [Javadocs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignChartDataset.html) which show this is as a concrete class with a public no-args constructor...

All of the otther JR types that I am importing from the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design` package are behaving perfectly fine...**what am I missing here?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK I was able to verify that this is in fact an abstract class, which technically answers my question. However I still cannot instantiate my JRDesignPieDataset, because its only valid constructor takes a JRDesignChartDataset subclass...but JRDesignPieDataset *is* a JRDesignChartDataset!!! Thats like a Car class that takes a Vehicle as a constructor parameter! Can someone please give me a valid example of how to instantiate a JRDesignPieDataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the recommended practice, but I've inherited some code that simply passes `null` into the constructor. Not sure what effect it has (if any), but it seems to get the job done.

```
JRDesignPieDataset data = new JRDesignPieDataset(null);
```

Comment: Weird! Thanks I'll give it a try - didn't even think of that as I figured it would break it for sure!